# Print content of a jquery-ui dialog box using @media print

Tags: jquery, css, printing, jquery-ui-dialog

The issue is generate a pdf document of a specific content.

The content of this document is being generated dinamicaly via javascript and being *append*ed(jquery) inside a jquery-ui dialog.

The css *@media print* code demands to print the div inside the dialog box.

The dialog box is ejected by a click event and shows the content, then a *Ctrl + P* action open the navigator print tool to show the preview.

The problem is that the content of the printed file is keeping just the appended html table structure but missing all the characters and most of the content.

[image]

Does it simply not work? or, am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#relatorioChecklist').append('<h3><a onclick="relatorioChecklist()">adfadfasdfas</a></h3><br>');

});


function relatorioChecklist() {

    $('#relatorioChecklist').append('<div id="myModal" class="modal"></div>');
    var str = '';
    $('#myModal').append('<div id="relatorio"><div id="cabecalho"><br><h2>Checklist Máquina</h2>'
                         +'<br><h2>ddghdh</h2><br></div><table class="tabela_checklist">'+
                '<thead><tr><th>Categoria</th><th>título da pergunta</th><th>Pergunta</th><th>Resposta</th><th>Operador</th>'+
                '<th>Bloqueio</th><th>Operador desbloq.</th></tr><thead>'+
                '<tbody>' + str + '</tbody></table><div id="rodape"><p>Assinatura supervisor: ____________________</p><p>Assinatura operador: ___________________</p>'+
                '</div></div>');
    $('#myModal').dialog({width: 900, height:1100});
    
    
}
```

```css
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #relatorio{
      visibility: visible;
  }
}
#relatorioChecklist {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#relatorioChecklist a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#relatorio{
    background-color: white;
    padding:50px;
}
#cabecalho{
    text-align:center;
}
#rodape{
    padding-top: 200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="relatorioChecklist">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, best to show all of your code as otherwise it will cause confusion to those trying to help :)

Comment: Done @jaydeeppatel